# В Android Studio отключается плагин Android Support

Tags: android, android-studio, плагин

Время от времени в Android Studio отключается плагин Android Support. С чем это может быть связано?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего это проблема самой среды разработки, поскольку например в данном случаи [в данном случаи](http://amyamyzhu.github.io/2018/09/18/Android-Support-Disabled-Error/)

проблема, как раз в среде.